# Missing values not replaced SAS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas

I am trying to replace missing values from D_Score numerical variable with 0. I dont get the values replaces and also no error. I am not sure what is the issue.

```
proc sql;
  create table Scores as
  select pa_id, 
        sum(D_I_score) as D_score, 
        sum(C_I_score) as C_score, 
        sum(R_I_score) as R_score, 
        sum(G_I_score) as G_score,  
            (case when  calculated D_score IS NULL then 0 else D_score end) as D_score

  from Join_G_ABS
  group by pa_id;
quit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two columns with the same name.  I think you want:

```
select pa_id, 
       coalesce(sum(D_I_score), 0) as D_score, 
       sum(C_I_score) as C_score, 
       sum(R_I_score) as R_score, 
       sum(G_I_score) as G_score
```

That is, do the definition "in place".  Also, `coalesce()` is simpler than the `case` logic you are using.

Comment: Yes, thats right. I see it works now. Thanks Gordon!! But I used calculated in my query because its the same variable "D_score" that doesn't work. I dont understand why.

Comment: @KDApril . . . The issue isn't the reference in the `case` expression.  The issue is the duplicate column names.